# Latest firmware for WRT54G version 6

Tags: firmware, wrt54g

Belkin bought Linksys in January 2014 and removed most of the firmware from the support website.

Is there an archive somewhere that has the latest firmeware for WRT54G version 6?

Comment: I'm also looking for the orginal WRT54GS v6 firmware. Can someone have a link to share?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the alternative (more advanced) firmwares from dd-wrt

www.dd-wrt.com/site/index

Answer (score 0):

Also [go to link](http://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=114663) found on Linksys site, under a previous version of WRT54G.

Comment: The WRT54GS runs vxworks not Linux, and Linksys never GPL'd the source code.